# Cantor measure not supported outside Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the [Cantor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585112/cantor-construction-is-continuous), which is continuous. Define the Cantor measure by $\mu((a,b))=f(b)-f(a)$ for $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Denote by $C$ the standard middle-third Cantor set.

How can we show that $\mu(E)=0$ for all $E\subseteq R$ such that $E\cap C=\emptyset$?

Our definition of $\mu$ is only defined for intervals $(a,b)$, and while we can use countable additivity of measure $\mu$, it is hard to see how to get to any such set $E$.

Comment: If $E\cap C=\emptyset$, is not $E$ a countable union of subsets of those open intervals which are excluded from the Cantor set? And is not the measure of any such open interval zero?

Comment: @Lubin You're right. I didn't realize that the number of intervals which are excluded from the Cantor set is countable.