# Weak convergence of measures for Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> For positive integer $k$, let $\mu_k=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\delta(x)+\delta\left(x-\dfrac{2}{3^k}\right)\right)$. Let $dC_k=\mu_1\ast\cdots\ast\mu_k$. In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585187/limit-of-convolution-of-measures-is-cantor-function), it was shown that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}dC_k((-\infty,x))=C(x),$$ where $C$ is the Cantor function.
>
> Show that $dC_k$ converges weakly to $\mu_C$.

By definition of weak convergence, we need to show that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb{R}fdC_k=\int_\mathbb{R}fd\mu_C$$ for any function $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. But it's not clear how to continue by using the result above.

Comment: Look at the portmanteau theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I see. I'm still interested in the proof of the general statement. Please look at my new question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585252/equivalence-of-definition-for-weak-convergence)