# Equivalence of definition for weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The [Wikipedia page on convergence of measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) says:

> In the case $S=\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, if $F_n, F$ denote the cumulative distribution functions of the measures $P_n$, $P$ respectively, then $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$ for all points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ at which $F$ is continuous.

I'm interested in the proof of the following:

> If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$ for all points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ at which $F$ is continuous, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb{R}gdF_n=\int_\mathbb{R}gdF$$ for any function $g\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts; for each $n$ you have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dF_n(x) = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty g'(x) F_n(x)\, dx$$
Now I think you can do the rest.